aws cloudfront path pattern is not being triggered
I have a cloudfront distro with two s3 buckets origins (see image)

each pointing to a different UI.
I have made both publicly accessible for testing, so I checked to make sure when I directly visit the s3 bucket URL, I can view the pages and both are working fine. Here are the s3 buckets - at the time of writing the stack is still available.
http://redrobottest-websitebucket75c24d94-uapi3y7mxxzx.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
http://redrobottest-translatorservicestackstaticwebsitede-yuxicqiq8awl.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
And I have defined path patterns, to route traffic to either s3 bucket depending if the pattern has matched. You can see the associated origins in the table list.

but when I go to the url:
https://d11ckeh3gftpjv.cloudfront.net/learn/apps/translator
it still trigger the default path which is this:
https://d11ckeh3gftpjv.cloudfront.net
I am not sure how to debug cloudfront - any gueses to what I am doing wrong? I have tried different pattern formats as well:

/learn/app/*
learn/app/*
/learn/app/traslate/*

and none worked
